# Meteor reactivity on contenteditable div has an issue, how can I resolve?

Tags: meteor

I have a div with an associated button that toggles the divs contenteditable true and false.

[image]

Once the div has been edited and the user clicks save I grab the inner html and store it in meteor like so:

```
Template.note.events
  'click #deleteNote': (e) ->
    currentNoteId = @_id
    Notes.remove currentNoteId, (error) ->
      if error
        Errors.throw('could not delete this note, contact support', false)
  'click #editNote': (e, t) ->
    note = t.find '.note-container'    
    classie.toggle t.find('.note'), 'focus'
    if t.$('.note').hasClass 'focus'
      $(e.target).text 'Save'
      editor.activate()
    else
      $(e.target).attr 'disabled'
      currentNoteId = @_id
      console.log note.innerHTML
      Notes.update currentNoteId,
        $set: 
          html: note.innerHTML
      , (error) ->
        if error
          console.log error
        editor.deactivate()
        $(e.target).text 'Edit'
        $(e.target).removeAttr 'disabled'
```

I noticed a weird bug. I know this is due to Meteors reactivity because if I disable the update command on the notes collection this doesn't happen.

If I edit the last line of text, or add a new line to the end of the content, Meteor automatically updates the div with the last line repeated twice. But then if I refresh the page the correct content shows up inside the note.

So the data is current in the database, but what is rendered on the screen due to reactivity does not reflect what is in the database. This is an error in how meteor updates the page. Any solution to this? Please let me know if you need more info, or if you find my explanation confusing.

**UPDATE**

So if I disable reactivity and manually render the template with server return data and append to DOM it works. So it is definitely a bug in how Meteor's reactivity works with contenteditable divs.

Heres the updated code with manual insert:

```
Template.note.events
  'click #deleteNote': (e, t) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    currentNoteId = @_id
    Notes.remove currentNoteId, (error) ->
      if error
        Errors.throw('could not delete this note, contact support', false)
      else
        t.__component__.dom.remove()
        return false
  'click #editNote': (e, t) ->
    note = t.find '.note-container'    
    classie.toggle t.find('.note'), 'focus'
    if t.$('.note').hasClass 'focus'
      $(e.target).text 'Save'
      editor.activate()
    else
      $(e.target).attr 'disabled'
      currentNoteId = @_id
      console.log note.innerHTML
      Notes.update currentNoteId,
        $set: 
          html: note.innerHTML
      , (error) ->
        if error
          console.log error
          Errors.throw('could not save this note, contact support', false)

        editor.deactivate()
        $(e.target).text 'Edit'
        $(e.target).removeAttr 'disabled'
```

**UPDATE 2**

So after more testing, I have come closer to understanding the issue. The issue is with Meteor reactively updating a divs content that has already been updated by the user using contenteditable feature.

So the user edits the contents of a div, and when the user finishes and clicks save, I grab the content and save it to the database. The div doesn't really need updating since the user already updated it and I am storing the result. But due to meteor's reactivity, it believes it needs to update the div, and it does so incorrectly.

So the issue is with Meteor reactively updating a DOM element that is already accurate because the update is based on what the user edited using contenteditable feature.

Comment: What version of meteor are you running?

Comment: I am running version 0.8.2

Comment: I found out this is an issue with the way Meteor handles reactivity on contenteditable divs. Check out github issue here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2328#issuecomment-49833061

Looks like Meteor might not be responsible for this update. So we would have to save and update the caret ourselves.

"You can just get carret position when saving contenteditable content and store it in the database. Later you can just read this position and move the caret into proper place. You have similar situation in application like Google Docs, they save caret's position of each user and display it accordingly."

I found the best caret package on the web to save and update the caret position, Rangy:

https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule

It really works great. I just save the caret position then update the document and in the callback restore the caret.

Answer (score 1):

Know this question is over a year old but here's how I tried to circumvent the issue.

Using iron-router

```
Router.route('/myroute', {
    waitOn: function(){
        return [Meteor.subscribe('collection', {data:params})];
    },
    action: {
        var myObject = Collection.findOne();
        this.render('myTemplate', {
            data: function(){
                return myObject;
            }
        });  
    }
};
```

*Le* template

```
<template name="panel-description">

    <b>Description</b>
    <div contenteditable data-name="description" class="can-edit">{{{ getDescription }}}</div>

</template>
```

Helper

```
Template.objectInfo.helpers({
    'getDescription': function(){
        if(typeof this.description !== 'undefined' && this.description !== null){
            return this.description;
        }
        else{
            return 'N/A';
        }
    },
});
```

The blur/focus events and respective method call

```
Template.objectInfo.events({
    'focus .can-edit' : function(e){
        // Get the description of myObject in currentData() so we can later compare for changes
        e.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-content', Template.currentData().description);
    },
    'blur .can-edit' : function(e){
        // Afer blur, store the content of our element
        var newData = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;

        // Compare if new content is diferent than previous one we stored in data-content 
        // attribute. Only make the server call if data changes.
        if(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-content') != newData){

            // Clear the element
            e.currentTarget.innerHTML = '';

            // The call to update our DB field.
            Meteor.call('saveObjectDescription', Template.currentData()._id, newData, function(err){
                // callback for error/success feedback
            });
        };

    },
});
```

It's a bit hacky, but does the trick.

After the route executes, the *getDescription* helper that returns *myObject*'s description. On blur, we check for a change in the previous content (stored in an attribute with the focus event) and if there are differences, make a call to the update method.

Meteor will instantly return the value through the helper but, in order to avoid the duplicated content issue, we clean the element just before the call.

It's a bit crude as the element flickering for a microsecond while the HTML is empty, besides that, it works.

PS: use triple brackets to render the helper as HTML.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1964#issuecomment-57948734

Resolved my issue, when text entered ny user appended before Helper variable.