# Meteor reactivity on contenteditable range selection issue + error with package

Tags: javascript, meteor, range, selection

Here is the issue: [Meteor reactivity on contenteditable div has an issue, how can I resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847885/meteor-reactivity-on-contenteditable-div-has-an-issue-how-can-i-resolve)

I found this https://libraries.io/meteor/mrt:rangy
and this https://libraries.io/meteor/maxharris9:rangy package

But I get this error `Discontiguous selection is not supported.`

Comment: You'll have to post some more details. If the library works, and the problem is in your code, how are we supposed to help? Write a minimal reproduction of the problem and post it. Try to keep it short :)

Comment: `  'input #window-oreo': function(e, tpl) {
    var oreoText = tpl.$('#window-oreo')[0].innerText;

    var savedSelection = rangy.saveSelection('#window-oreo');
    Session.set('plainTextKitkat', oreoText);
    Session.set('plainTextOreo', oreoText);
  },

  'blur #window-oreo': function(e, tpl) {
    rangy.restoreSelection(savedSelection);
    console.log(rangy.restoreSelection(savedSelection));
  },`     #window-oreo is editable div element.